# How to use Vanillajs + external node_modules script in an ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, node-modules

This is for devleopment use only.

I would like to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-recorder in an existing ember app: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web

All I want it the script to load and run this code, new TestRecorder()

What is the minimal pain free solution?

Comment: ember-browserify

Comment: @Lux its a world of pain when importing webpack built stuff: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6954

Answer (score 0):

Until ember supports npm out of the box, the easiet way for me is to copy to the vendor then import in ember-cli-build.js :

package.json:

`"copy": "cp node_modules/test-recorder/build/test-recorder.js vendor && cp node_modules/test-recorder/build/test-recorder.js.map vendor"`

ember-cli-build.js :

`app.import('vendor/test-recorder.js');`

Comment: I would do this with a simple funnel + merge-tree. So you can do it in your build process. Should be very simple with an in-repo-addon.

Comment: You can try [ember-cli-node-assets](https://github.com/dfreeman/ember-cli-node-assets) addon. It works perfectly for me and in simple cases [you don't even need to use ``app.import``](https://github.com/dfreeman/ember-cli-node-assets#import-shorthand).

Comment: @GennadyDogaev fair enough, I'll add that as an option in the readme sometime, even better maybe you could test it and raise a pr? https://github.com/QuantumInformation/test-recorder/blob/master/README.md#importing-the-test-recorder-into-an-ember-cli-project

Comment: I don't think I'll have a chance to test it in near future